# Virtualbox Docker-Machine "invalid volume specification"

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I tried different ways to set the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` to 1, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: FOR docker_test Cannot create container for service test: 
invalid volume specification: 
'C:\Users\my_user\test\cert_file.pfx:/root/.aspnet/https/https_cert.pfx:ro'
```

I tried everything I could find online so far. These are my settings. Anyone who can spot the issue? I use Docker-toolbox instead of Docker for Windows on my Windows machine, because I use Virtualbox as well (and I cannot run VT-x and Hypervisor at the same time). I guess I keep getting this error, because I have to set this environment variable on a different place, perhaps.

Last part docker-compose.yml

```
   secrets:
      - source: cert
        target: /root/.aspnet/https/https_cert.pfx
secrets:
    cert:
        file: cert_file.pfx
```

config.yml (`/Users/my_user/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json`)

```
HostOptions: {
    "Env": [
        "COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1"
    ]
}
```

Powershell:

```
PS C:\> $env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

Anyone who can spot the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base images from Microsoft seem te have some issues with Docker Toolbox, see https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/177#issuecomment-481332463. So these lines in docker-compose.yml to copy files to the container don't work:

```
   secrets:
      - source: cert
        target: /root/.aspnet/https/https_cert.pfx
secrets:
    cert:
        file: cert_file.pfx
```

The error is a bit unclear, cause you think the issue is `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` which isn't.

The solution to this problem is to replace the lines with a simple volume:

```
volumes:
    - ./cert_file.pfx:/root.aspnet/https/https_cert.pfx
```